# Angular 6 git diff coverage

Tags: angular, git, unit-testing, code-coverage

I am able to run ng test with code coverage option and it is giving code coverage for the entire package. Now I want to know the git diff coverage report against master branch as we have checks remote repo to have 95% diff coverage so before submitting code into remote repo we want to check locally.

We are using Angular 6.

I need help to configure this.

Comment: Checkout and test both branches?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/istanbul-diff this looks like something that might be helpful. I haven't managed to get it working though.